# How to find value of a row based on values between start and ending condition?

Tags: mysql

I have been working on a table to get the end timestamp of a play (`nowPlaying`) event based on the following conditions:

1. If there is a `browseSearch` between `nowPlaying` and `browseFind`, then the case is ignored.
2. `browseFind` would be the starting point for each of the `nowPlaying` event.
3. There could be any number of other events between a `browseFind` and `nowPlaying`.

What I have done is tried to partition the query and add another column with `Start, Break, Skip and end` as shown in table below:

The events are ordered by timestamp `event_ts`

```
+------+--------------+-------+---------------------+
| id   | page_type    | p_t   | event_ts            |
+------+--------------+-------+---------------------+
|    1 | browseFind   | Start | 2021-01-01 06:00:00 |
|    1 | browseSearch | break | 2021-01-01 06:00:10 |
|    1 | browseFind   | Start | 2021-01-01 06:01:00 |
|    1 | x-ray        | skip  | 2021-01-01 06:01:30 |
|    1 | browseSearch | break | 2021-01-01 06:02:00 |
|    1 | nowPlaying   | end   | 2021-01-01 06:03:00 |
|    1 | browseFind   | Start | 2021-01-01 06:10:00 |
|    1 | abc          | skip  | 2021-01-01 06:11:00 |
|    1 | abc          | skip  | 2021-01-01 06:12:00 |
|    1 | nowPlaying   | end   | 2021-01-01 06:12:00 |
+------+--------------+-------+---------------------+
```

The only valid timestamp would be the last one `2021-01-01 06:12:00` because rest have break in between their `Start` and `End`. Also if there is no `end` and a `start` follows, then the loop will reset.

I saw a bunch of post on SO, but it was not done in SQL, but rather programmatically.
How can I use the p_t column to write a SQL that will look at events between the start and end if it exists and get the valid timestamp of `end`

My Query:

```
select id,
page_type,
case when page_type in ('browseFind') then 'Start' 
     when page_type in ('browseSearch') then 'break'
     when page_type not in ('browseFind','nowPlaying') then 'skip'
     when page_type in ('nowPlaying') then 'end'
end as p_t,
event_ts
from steps
order by event_ts;
```

Queries for DDL:

```
create table steps (id int, page_type varchar(100), event_ts timestamp);

insert into steps values (1,'browseFind','2021-01-01 6:00:00');
insert into steps values (1,'browseSearch','2021-01-01 6:00:10');
insert into steps values (1,'browseFind','2021-01-01 6:01:00');
insert into steps values (1,'x-ray','2021-01-01 6:01:30');
insert into steps values (1,'browseSearch','2021-01-01 6:02:00');
insert into steps values (1,'nowPlaying','2021-01-01 6:03:00');
insert into steps values (1,'browseFind','2021-01-01 6:10:00');
insert into steps values (1,'abc','2021-01-01 6:11:00');
insert into steps values (1,'abc','2021-01-01 6:12:00');
insert into steps values (1,'nowPlaying','2021-01-01 6:12:00');
```

Comment: What is desired output? one row with `event_ts = '2021-01-01 06:12:00'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need in this:

```sql
WITH
cte AS ( SELECT id, page_type, event_ts, 
                LAG(page_type) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY event_ts) lag_page_type
         FROM steps
         WHERE page_type IN ('browseFind', 'browseSearch', 'nowPlaying') )
SELECT id, page_type, event_ts
FROM cte
WHERE page_type = 'nowPlaying'
  AND lag_page_type = 'browseFind';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=735c85d735509ebf68524cbcb1eb34a0)